# How to calculate the average value (per column) of the data that have the same ID in the first column?

Tags: text-processing, awk, data

I want to calculate the average value of my data when they have the same ID in the first column. I want to calculate the average values for the remaining columns that have the same value in the first column. I know how to do it for one column, but I got difficulty in doing the average for the whole columns I have.

Here is my sample data
File name: abraham

```
year    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
1929    7.5 0   7.78    3.695   1.139   0.186   -0.074  -0.205  -0.323  -0.434  -0.539  -0.639  -0.735  -0.916  -1.085  -1.241  -1.387  -1.522  -1.818  -2.058  -2.247  -2.389  -2.488  -2.551  -2.582  -2.521  -2.404  -2.262  -2.118  -1.987  -1.872  -1.775  -1.691  -1.628  -1.578  -1.484  -1.395  -1.311  -1.229  -1.151  -1.075  -1.002  -0.859  -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.559
1929    6.11    0   6.112   3.536   1.227   0.252   -0.063  -0.201  -0.32   -0.43   -0.535  -0.634  -0.73   -0.91   -1.078  -1.234  -1.379  -1.512  -1.806  -2.046  -2.236  -2.378  -2.478  -2.54   -2.573  -2.515  -2.402  -2.262  -2.119  -1.988  -1.873  -1.776  -1.692  -1.629  -1.578  -1.484  -1.395  -1.311  -1.229  -1.151  -1.075  -1.002  -0.859  -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.559
1929    2.22    0   2.227   2.542   1.022   0.222   -0.058  -0.198  -0.317  -0.427  -0.531  -0.63   -0.725  -0.905  -1.072  -1.227  -1.371  -1.505  -1.798  -2.038  -2.227  -2.37   -2.471  -2.533  -2.567  -2.512  -2.4    -2.262  -2.12   -1.989  -1.874  -1.776  -1.693  -1.63   -1.579  -1.485  -1.395  -1.311  -1.229  -1.151  -1.075  -1.002  -0.859  -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.559
1929    2.78    0   2.779   1.993   0.819   0.18    -0.056  -0.195  -0.314  -0.424  -0.527  -0.626  -0.721  -0.9    -1.066  -1.221  -1.364  -1.498  -1.79   -2.03   -2.219  -2.362  -2.464  -2.526  -2.562  -2.509  -2.399  -2.262  -2.12   -1.99   -1.875  -1.777  -1.693  -1.63   -1.579  -1.485  -1.396  -1.311  -1.229  -1.151  -1.075  -1.002  -0.859  -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.559
1930    0.83    0   0.833   0.85    0.354   0.073   -0.052  -0.187  -0.305  -0.414  -0.517  -0.614  -0.708  -0.885  -1.049  -1.202  -1.344  -1.477  -1.768  -2.006  -2.196  -2.34   -2.442  -2.508  -2.549  -2.5    -2.395  -2.261  -2.122  -1.992  -1.877  -1.779  -1.695  -1.631  -1.58   -1.485  -1.396  -1.311  -1.23   -1.151  -1.076  -1.002  -0.859  -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.559
1930    -0.28   0   -0.278  0.461   0.242   0.049   -0.052  -0.185  -0.302  -0.411  -0.513  -0.61   -0.704  -0.88   -1.044  -1.196  -1.338  -1.47   -1.761  -1.999  -2.188  -2.332  -2.435  -2.502  -2.544  -2.498  -2.394  -2.261  -2.122  -1.992  -1.878  -1.779  -1.695  -1.631  -1.581  -1.486  -1.396  -1.312  -1.23   -1.152  -1.076  -1.002  -0.859  -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.559
1930    0.56    0.002   0.511   0.348   0.165   0.033   -0.052  -0.183  -0.299  -0.407  -0.509  -0.607  -0.7    -0.875  -1.038  -1.19   -1.332  -1.463  -1.753  -1.991  -2.18   -2.325  -2.429  -2.496  -2.54   -2.495  -2.393  -2.261  -2.123  -1.993  -1.878  -1.78   -1.696  -1.632  -1.581  -1.486  -1.396  -1.312  -1.23   -1.152  -1.076  -1.002  -0.859  -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.559
1930    3.89    0   3.884   0.96    0.243   0.041   -0.052  -0.181  -0.297  -0.404  -0.506  -0.603  -0.696  -0.87   -1.033  -1.184  -1.325  -1.457  -1.746  -1.983  -2.173  -2.318  -2.422  -2.49   -2.536  -2.492  -2.391  -2.26   -2.123  -1.994  -1.879  -1.78   -1.696  -1.632  -1.581  -1.486  -1.397  -1.312  -1.23   -1.152  -1.076  -1.002  -0.86   -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.558
1931    -7.22   0.057   -4.563  -0.299  0.035   0.007   -0.054  -0.175  -0.286  -0.391  -0.49   -0.585  -0.676  -0.847  -1.007  -1.156  -1.295  -1.425  -1.711  -1.947  -2.136  -2.282  -2.389  -2.46   -2.514  -2.478  -2.384  -2.259  -2.125  -1.996  -1.882  -1.783  -1.698  -1.633  -1.582  -1.487  -1.397  -1.312  -1.231  -1.152  -1.076  -1.003  -0.86   -0.722  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.307   0.444   0.558
1931    -6.11   0.057   -4.1    -0.663  0.004   -0.001  -0.055  -0.174  -0.284  -0.388  -0.487  -0.581  -0.672  -0.843  -1.002  -1.151  -1.289  -1.419  -1.704  -1.94   -2.129  -2.275  -2.382  -2.454  -2.51   -2.476  -2.383  -2.258  -2.125  -1.997  -1.883  -1.783  -1.698  -1.633  -1.583  -1.487  -1.397  -1.312  -1.231  -1.152  -1.076  -1.003  -0.86   -0.722  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.307   0.444   0.558
1931    -10.28  0.057   -6.362  -1.527  0   -0.001  -0.055  -0.173  -0.283  -0.386  -0.484  -0.578  -0.668  -0.839  -0.997  -1.145  -1.283  -1.413  -1.697  -1.933  -2.122  -2.268  -2.376  -2.448  -2.506  -2.473  -2.382  -2.258  -2.125  -1.998  -1.883  -1.784  -1.698  -1.633  -1.583  -1.487  -1.398  -1.312  -1.231  -1.152  -1.076  -1.003  -0.86   -0.722  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.307   0.444   0.558
1931    -10 0.057   -7.018  -2.259  -0.001  -0.001  -0.056  -0.172  -0.281  -0.384  -0.481  -0.575  -0.665  -0.834  -0.992  -1.14   -1.278  -1.406  -1.691  -1.926  -2.115  -2.261  -2.369  -2.443  -2.501  -2.47   -2.38   -2.258  -2.125  -1.998  -1.884  -1.784  -1.699  -1.634  -1.583  -1.487  -1.398  -1.313  -1.231  -1.152  -1.076  -1.003  -0.86   -0.722  -0.588  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.307   0.444   0.558
```

desired output

```
year    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
1929    4.6525  0   4.7245  2.9415  1.05175 0.21    -0.06275    -0.19975    -0.3185 -0.42875    -0.533  -0.63225    -0.72775    -0.90775    -1.07525    -1.23075    -1.37525    -1.50925    -1.803  -2.043  -2.23225    -2.37475    -2.47525    -2.5375 -2.571  -2.51425    -2.40125    -2.262  -2.11925    -1.9885 -1.8735 -1.776  -1.69225    -1.62925    -1.5785 -1.4845 -1.39525    -1.311  -1.229  -1.151  -1.075  -1.002  -0.859  -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.559
1930    1.25    0.0005  1.2375  0.65475 0.251   0.049   -0.052  -0.184  -0.30075    -0.409  -0.51125    -0.6085 -0.702  -0.8775 -1.041  -1.193  -1.33475    -1.46675    -1.757  -1.99475    -2.18425    -2.32875    -2.432  -2.499  -2.54225    -2.49625    -2.39325    -2.26075    -2.1225 -1.99275    -1.878  -1.7795 -1.6955 -1.6315 -1.58075    -1.48575    -1.39625    -1.31175    -1.23   -1.15175    -1.076  -1.002  -0.85925    -0.721  -0.587  -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.308   0.445   0.55875
1931    -8.4025 0.057   -5.51075    -1.187  0.0095  0.001   -0.055  -0.1735 -0.2835 -0.38725    -0.4855 -0.57975    -0.67025    -0.84075    -0.9995 -1.148  -1.28625    -1.41575    -1.70075    -1.9365 -2.1255 -2.2715 -2.379  -2.45125    -2.50775    -2.47425    -2.38225    -2.25825    -2.125  -1.99725    -1.883  -1.7835 -1.69825    -1.63325    -1.58275    -1.487  -1.3975 -1.31225    -1.231  -1.152  -1.076  -1.003  -0.86   -0.722  -0.58725    -0.456  -0.328  -0.171  -0.017  0.068   0.151   0.307   0.444   0.558
```

Comment: I was using the following script, but it just calculates the first column only.                                     #!/bin/bash
awk '
 NR==1{print;next}
 $1!=l && NR>2{print l,n;n=0}
 {n+=i++;l=$1}
 END{if (NR>1) print l,n}' < abraham > annual.result

Comment: I tried this but still have the second column only averaged #!/bin/bash
awk '
NR==1{print; next}
    {v[$1]+=$2+;n[$1]++}
    END{for (i in n) print i, v[i]/n[i]}' abraham

Comment: Your sample files are a bit vague. It looks like you removed linebreaks?

Comment: Not sure but wouldn't be array of array useful? GNU awk is associative...

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array to store a sum of each columns' values, and when $1 changes, get the average from there.

```
# print header
NR==1 {
    print
    next
}

# print average of each column per year
#  then, reset columns sums and number of lines
function print_sum() {
    printf prev
    # needs GNU awk, for length of array
    for (i=2; i < length(sum) + 2; i++) {
            printf FS sum[i]/nlines
            sum[i] = 0
    }
    printf ORS
    nlines = 0
}

# print average when $1 changes, but not the first time
# also, on end of script
NR>2 && prev!=$1 { print_sum() }
END              { print_sum() }

# for every line with the same $1, sum column values, increment number of lines
{
    prev=$1;
    nlines++
    for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) {
            sum[i]+=$i
    }
}
```

Comment: And if the order of years would be not sorted? I'm just curious...

Comment: Then, you'd need to use a pseudo 2-d array (`arr[i, j]`), and an array of number of lines, and would need `*years` the memory needed by this solution.

Comment: This won't print the results for the last id, 1931 in this case, since $1 won't change before the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Perl solution. It does not expect the years to be sorted but does need to read the entire file (well, the sums of each column at least) into memory. As long as your file is not too big, it should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

## Read the input file, line by line
while (<>){
    ## Print and skip the 1st line
    if($.==1){
    print; 
    next
    }; 
    ## Split the fileds into the array @F
    @F=split(/\s+/);

    ## $k (%k) is a hash of hashes. The first element of 
    ## $F ($F[0]) is the year, so $k{$year}{tot} will be 
    ## the nuber of lines for each year.
    $k{$F[0]}{tot}++;

    ## Go through each field add its value
    ## to $k{$year}{field number}
    for($i=1;$i<=$#F;$i++){
    $k{$F[0]}{$i}+=$F[$i];
    }
 }
## Now print the data for each year
foreach $y (sort keys(%k)){
    ## $y is the year
    print "$y "; 
    ## $k{$y}{$i} is the sum of the values for this column/year
    ## and $k{$y}{tot} is the number of lines for this year
    for($i=1;$i<=$#F;$i++){
    print " " . $k{$y}{$i}/$k{$y}{tot};

    }
    print "\n";
}
```

And here is the same script as a (longish) one liner:

```
$ perl -ane '$.==1 && do {print; next}; $k{$F[0]}{tot}++;
           for($i=1;$i<=$#F;$i++){$k{$F[0]}{$i}+=$F[$i];}
           END{foreach $y (sort keys(%k)){
                    print "$y "; 
                    for($i=1;$i<=$#F;$i++){
                      print " " . $k{$y}{$i}/$k{$y}{tot};
                    } print "\n";} }' abraham 
year    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
1929  4.6525 0 4.7245 2.9415 1.05175 0.21 -0.06275 -0.19975 -0.3185 -0.42875 -0.533 -0.63225 -0.72775 -0.90775 -1.07525 -1.23075 -1.37525 -1.50925 -1.803 -2.043 -2.23225 -2.37475 -2.47525 -2.5375 -2.571 -2.51425 -2.40125 -2.262 -2.11925 -1.9885 -1.8735 -1.776 -1.69225 -1.62925 -1.5785 -1.4845 -1.39525 -1.311 -1.229 -1.151 -1.075 -1.002 -0.859 -0.721 -0.587 -0.456 -0.328 -0.171 -0.017 0.068 0.151 0.308 0.445 0.559
1930  1.25 0.0005 1.2375 0.65475 0.251 0.049 -0.052 -0.184 -0.30075 -0.409 -0.51125 -0.6085 -0.702 -0.8775 -1.041 -1.193 -1.33475 -1.46675 -1.757 -1.99475 -2.18425 -2.32875 -2.432 -2.499 -2.54225 -2.49625 -2.39325 -2.26075 -2.1225 -1.99275 -1.878 -1.7795 -1.6955 -1.6315 -1.58075 -1.48575 -1.39625 -1.31175 -1.23 -1.15175 -1.076 -1.002 -0.85925 -0.721 -0.587 -0.456 -0.328 -0.171 -0.017 0.068 0.151 0.308 0.445 0.55875
1931  -8.4025 0.057 -5.51075 -1.187 0.0095 0.001 -0.055 -0.1735 -0.2835 -0.38725 -0.4855 -0.57975 -0.67025 -0.84075 -0.9995 -1.148 -1.28625 -1.41575 -1.70075 -1.9365 -2.1255 -2.2715 -2.379 -2.45125 -2.50775 -2.47425 -2.38225 -2.25825 -2.125 -1.99725 -1.883 -1.7835 -1.69825 -1.63325 -1.58275 -1.487 -1.3975 -1.31225 -1.231 -1.152 -1.076 -1.003 -0.86 -0.722 -0.58725 -0.456 -0.328 -0.171 -0.017 0.068 0.151 0.307 0.444 0.558
```

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu` [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
{ head -n 1; datamash -s -g 1 $(printf 'mean %s ' {2..54}); } <infile
```

where `54` is the number of columns. This assumes your fields are tab-separated. If they're space-separated run

```
{ head -n 1; datamash -t ' ' -s -g 1 $(printf 'mean %s ' {2..54}); } <infile
```

or if they're separated by multiple blanks (spaces/tabs):

```
{ head -n 1; datamash -W -s -g 1 $(printf 'mean %s ' {2..54}); } <infile
```

Note that the output will be sorted by first column.